# Automatic readjust size of widgets when changing size of MainWindow

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I designed a PyQt5 GUI (MainWindow) with QtDesigner.
Therefore i "dragged and dropped" the Widgets into the MainWindow and put them where i wanted them.

Everything worked perfectly fine so far.

However, when i wanted to open the application in FullScreen, those Widgets are not getting Resized.

Some research-time later, it seems like i have done an oopsie, as i have not used any specific layout... Am i right?

But i still have some hope that somebody have had the same issue before and maybe fixed it.
I also tried several things myself, like setting the SizePolicy of the Widgets to expanding. But nothing worked.

I also provided a minimalistic Code, which has the same Error.

Python Script:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys
class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__() # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
        uic.loadUi('Test.ui', self) # Load the .ui file
        self.show() # Show the GUI
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.button1_clicked)

    def button1_clicked(self):
        self.label1.setText("Who is there?")
        
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

Test.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>931</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="button1">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>300</x>
      <y>160</y>
      <width>261</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Knock Knock</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label1">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>330</x>
      <y>250</y>
      <width>221</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>-----------------------------------</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>931</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Can someone help me out or is there no other way than using a specific Layout?

Greetings :)

Comment: Your "layout" is just you placing widgets at specific geometries (positions and sizes); instead, you need to properly use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), and you can do it from [Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) too. Just remember that the layouts shown in the widget box are only intended as *children* layouts (*nested* into other layouts), the main layout of a window or a container must be set using the context menu (or the toolbar buttons) after selecting the *container*, not its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what YOU mean by "specific layout", but that phrase describes exactly what you have done here -- you have placed and sized each component with specific X and Y coordinates directly.  There is no code here to do any resizing.  The correct way to use Qt is to use a layout.  Then the layout manager will manage all the resizing for you.  It take a little bit to grasp the philosophy of layouts and sizers, but the result is well worth the effort.  You'll never have to worry about X and Y again.

Here is the layout guide:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends how did you create your layout.. Did you set your MainWindow object to grid layout? If your widgets doesn't resize it is possible that you did't set your MainWindow object layout.It should look gray in the top left if you've put the grid layout and you must select your MainWindow object[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juouo.png)